# Keep getting the error "command is not found"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
class ModCommands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    def create_command_embed(self, ctx):
      moderator=ctx.author.display_name
      disc_server=ctx.guild_name
      reason= None
      ban_dm_embed=create_command_embed(self, ctx,
      "**Banned**", 
      "https://discord.gg/UQVB7hVTav",
      f"You were banned from {disc_server}",
      discord.Color.red(),
      f"Moderator{moderator}",
      ctx.author.avatar_url,
      f"`Reason: {reason}`",
      "`Case Number: [COMING SOON]`",
      '\u200b' "Spoon Bot",
      "https://i.imgur.com/gj4Veji.png")
      return ban_dm_embed

    @commands.command()
    async def ban(self, ctx):
        await ctx.message.reply(ban_dm_embed)
```

Whenever I run the code I get the error:

> Command 'ban' is not found

When I type "ban" in discord. I'm using an embed handler to make my embeds so that's why I use `create_command_embed`. I want to try make the embed before doing the async def as I think it looks cleaner.

I'm using cogs for my bot.

Comment: Apologies for the typo, i meant to say "ban" instead of "bantest"

Comment: Was the cog registered? Also, `ban_dm_embed` doesn't exist, you have to call `self.create_command_embed` first. Then, that tries to call itself in a never-ending recursive loop (not to mention that you need the `self.` to access the function at all, or use the class and pass in the instance as the first argument).

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve]. It should be *minimal* and runnable (don't include any tokens).

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1:** If You Are Using Discord.py V2 If You Use on_message Event Commands Will Get Bugged

**Solution 2:** How Did You Created That Embed ? Just Use ( discord.Embed( ) ) Why Are You Using Return? You Are Sending Embed. Soo Shouldnt You Use ctx.send(embed=ban_dm_embed) ?

**Solution 3:** Did You Added setup function on The Bottom of Your Code?

Comment: If you do not have enough details to answer the question, you should flag the question as needing details or clarity. You should not answer with multiple solutions as Stack Overflow is not a help desk, it's a place for **specific** questions *and answers*